# problem initializing map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Hi it's something that can't understand why this doesn't work??

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

var map;
var latLng;
var varZoom;

function initialize() {

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "SetMarkers.aspx/findMapParameters",
    data: "{idMapa: '" + idMap + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (values) {

        var location = values.d.split(",");
        var lat = parseFloat(location[0]);
        var lng = parseFloat(location[1]);
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        varZoom = location[2];

    }
});

//build the map for the first time
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.965754, -64.577637),
    zoom: varZoom, //this makes the difference
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});

}
```

**Edit**

it's not a problem with called to the aspx method because i already debbug with charles and work's fine. Also it's not a problem with the values because if i type the value direct into the script like this

```
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.965754, -64.577637),
    zoom: 6, //<<<<---like this works
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

it's works. Also it's a problem with the center

The problem it's that the map doesn't show

Comment: *How* does it not work? What part of it? What's the symptom? What happens when you walk through with a debugger? What do your various variables look like at various times?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i edited the question

Comment: ...And yet didn't address the questions I raised. When you walk through your *client-side* code with a debugger, what do you see happening? I mean, clearly `varZoom` won't have the right value, the question is why not? If you step through the code, settings breakpoints within the ajax `success` callback and where you're creating the map, you'll probably be able to see what's going wrong. If you're unsure about client-side debugging, it's a breeze, and the tools are free -- you probably already have them: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html (BTW, not my downvote or close vote)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry but i also used the debbugg kit of chrome and the value that i get in the var `varZoom` it's correct

Comment: Something else must be different between the failing case and your test case where you say `6` works. If `varZoom` contains `6`, then the point you've highlighted in the code, there is literally **no** difference in what gets passed into `google.maps.Map` whether you use a literal `6` or `varZoom`, because it's a right-hand value and so the *value* `6` gets assigned to `zoom` and passed in, whether it's coming from a literal or from `varZoom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved mi problem i don't know really how to explain, but when i debug the code I'm realize that somehow jquery don't let that google maps render avoiding create the map so i solved the problem like this.

**make the ajax code only to fill this goblal vars then it's when build the map**

```
var zoom;
var lat;
var lng

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "SetMarkers.aspx/findMapParameters",
    data: "{idMapa: '" + idMap + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: response
});

/*****take the vars and set the new map****/
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});

/***Sets the values in the map****/
function response(values) {

    var location = values.d.split(",");
    lat = parseFloat(location[0]);
    lng = parseFloat(location[1]);
   zoom = parseInt(location[2]);
   return false;
}
```